# SQL : How to create a row per period value

Tags: sql, pivot

I am currently trying to upskill myself within data analysis using tools such as SQL, EXCEL etc. So apologies, if what I am asking for may not make much sense, but happy to expand/clarify where required.

Problem :

I am trying to create a period by period line graph, showing pay across periods. However, with my current dataset the rows are :

employee codes and the columns are the individual periods with the values pertaining to that period for each row.

In order to achieve the requirements for my line graph. I would need to perform pivot of some sort to create a row per period for each worker. This will then allow me to group by periods for my line graph.

Current dataset :

```
Code    Name    Period 1    Period 2    Period 3
P1  Worker 1    2740.67 0   0
2   Worker 2    0   0   0
3   Worker 3    0   759.85  607.88
4   Worker 4    0   0   0
5   Worker 5    5000    5000    5000
6   Worker 6    1762.5  1672.5  960
12  Worker 7    6050    7750    5000
7   Worker 8    625.38  748.46  10
1234    Worker 9    2616.67 2616.67 2616.67
8   Worker 10   500 200 0
144 Worker 11   0   0   0
M100    Worker 12   423.08  0   0
M01 Worker 13   1583.33 1583.33 1583.33
M102    Worker 14   5833.33 5833.33 0
2403    Worker 15   8333.33 8333.33 11269.23
```

[image: tbl screenshot]

So for worker 5 they should have have 3 rows. The only thing i can think of is subqueries per worker that make up the columns or multiple unions, but seems rather time consuming ? Was hoping for a quicker efficient way of achieving what i need.

Comment: You can union something like `SELECT Code, Name, "Period 1" WHERE "Period 1" != 0`  with similar queries for Period 2 and 3?

Comment: You should have only one period column and one Value, and not period 1 2 and 3, UNION would be the choice a UNION ALL is faster

Comment: select 
code,
name,
'Period 1',
payperiod1
from pay p
join Emp details er
on p.p_id = er.er_id
union
select 
code,
name,
'Period 2',
payperiod2
from pay p
join Emp details er
on p.p_id = er.er_id


Thats what i originally thought but seems tedius, especially if the list continues to grow. Need something more dynamic